# Enhanced ecommerce not showing product performance revenue

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

So I have an implementation of enhanced ecommerce for google analytics. On the complete page it fires:

```
function transactionComplete(products, transaction){
    for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        var product = products[i];
        ga('ec:addProduct', {
            'id': product.productId,
            'name': product.productName,
            'category': product.productCategory,
            'price': product.productPrice,
            'quantity': Number(product.productQuantity)
        });
    }

    ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
        'id': transaction.id,
        'affiliation': transaction.name,
        'revenue': transaction.total,
        'tax': '0',
        'shipping': transaction.shipping
    });

    ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```

Fairly simple right?

Well when I look at the dashboard, Product performance does not show any revenue. However sales performance does. Am I doing something wrong?

Screenshots: 
Sales Performance
[image: Sales Performance]

Product Performance
[image: Product Performance]

Answer (score 1):

Use [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) and make sure the product information is being sent to GA.

Your products may have a comma or any other character causing sintax errors (not detected as javascript errors), this would produce exactly what the snapshots are showing: the transaction is ok, the products are not.

Actually both parts of the code are completely individual (as the go to different reports within GA). In case you detect no failure then I recommend you to go to the [Enhanced Ecommerce Demo Store](http://enhancedecommerce.appspot.com) and copy exactly the products' code in the transactions so you can start including your dynamic values line by line until you find where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem. Although it took me hours to figure it out, turns out the solution is quite simple. My mistake was that I wasn't assigning a price to the product. Even though the revenue was reported and my single product was being associated with that transactions, since there was no price for the product, none of the revenue was being allocated to it. I incorrectly assumed that for a single product transaction, the revenue would be assigned to it. As for your particular case, I suspect that your product pricing was incorrect (either null or in an invalid format) which is similar to Andres answer.

Answer (score 1):

you have to be very consistent across everywhere, for me also the same thing happened, I was not able to view revenue since I didn't update quantity, on updating quantity product SKU aka no..etc, it started showing me data!!

Comment: Hey, can you please expand on your answer!

Comment: This helped. I was missing `quantity: 1` in each item on the purchase event. Also price may need to be a string like '20.00' - although I'm not 100% sure.